# Nav2d with 2 laser scanners

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy commuity,

is it possible to use 2 observation sources e.g. laser scanners with the nav2d package?
I was wondering if I could use following solution: https://answers.ros.org/question/34095/add-two-laser-for-navigation/

Thanks a lot!

Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323066/nav2d-with-2-laser-scanners/) by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2019-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that would work.

---

Originally posted by [Veera Ragav](https://answers.ros.org/users/29301/veera-ragav/) with karma: 240 on 2019-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2019-05-14**:
Indeed, worked out! Just added second laser-topic and nodes were subscribing to it. Thanks